# How can I use a bind mount in docker-compose and still preserve node_modules?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, node-modules, docker-volume

I am trying to build and run an image based on this  [docker course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jotpVtFwYBk&t=21s). The goal is to have a bind mount that allows me to sync source code changes with the running container, but also to preserve the `node_modules` directory of the image that is created during the image build. The video recommends using the following:

```
services:
  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:ro
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up --build`,
it gives me this error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4af0c23016b50a7ea3ce1dffe0af69fcb2a0e1b18f2444c9d6b02bb31e557fe3/_data" to rootfs at "/app/node_modules": mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8af3fad3cb0cd9ac95e1dae61c88560e37630870be29002625e6112efa1f0f8c/merged/app/node_modules: read-only file system: unknown

Which appears to be because I am overlaying a writable volume on a read only volume, but I have no idea how to solve that issue.

I have tried using a `src` sub-directory to house my `index.js` on a different level as `node_modules`, but that starts to feel like spaghetti, and I don't want to have to set up a bunch of environment variables in `package.json` or the `Dockerfile` just to have a reusable setup. (I also prefer being able to just use `node index.js` for the production version of the image.)

I really just want to know a proper way to do this without any headache, something simple and ergonomic.

If I am just overthinking this, or if the subdirectory is the best way, that is fine too, I just can't seem to find good solutions, or any standard ways of doing this.

Also, if it matters, I am on linux.

Supremely grateful for any and all answers, as I am sure I will learn something from all of them.

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I do not want to have node_modules in my development directory, just in the container.

Comment: Remove `:ro` on `/app`

Comment: Do you have a `node_modules` folder in your development directory? Even an empty one.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks for the response, I would use this but I don't want to have the possibility of accidentally changing things on the host directory from the container

Comment: @BMitch Thanks for the response, but no, I have removed all instances of ```node_modules``` from the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount requires that a directory exists on the parent filesystem where the mount is performed. So you can't do both, a read-only filesystem, and no `node_modules` folder in that filesystem.

The solution is to either:

- Remove the `:ro` from the parent folder volume, which will result in a `node_modules` folder being created in there on container start.
- Creating the `node_modules` folder in the development directory.

The folder can (or will) be empty, and you'll use the contents of the image, this is just a requirement for the mount syscall.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the empty directory approach and it worked flawlessly. I appreciate the explanation. Thanks again.